# grunt-contrib-jshint ignores has no effect

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I would like to exclude `libs` directory from being lint'ed.  However, `ignores` in `options` and planted `.jshintignore` file in project directory won't make `libs` to be excluded.

```js
 jshint: {
  options: {
    smarttabs: true,
    ignores: ['public/js/libs/**/*.js']
  },

  all: [
        'Gruntfile.js', 
        'public/js/**/*.js'
      ]

},
```

grunt version:

```
 grunt-cli v0.1.11
 grunt v0.4.2
 grunt-contrib-jshint@0.7.2
```

What did I miss out?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`ignores` is a jshint option and expects specific files. It's better to use the idiomatic Grunt negate `!` to exclude files:

```js
jshint: {
  options: {
    smarttabs: true
  },
  all: [
    'Gruntfile.js', 
    'public/js/**/*.js',
    '!public/js/libs/**/*.js'
  ],
},
```

See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

Comment: Double check the pattern. Also try `grunt --verbose` to see the files it is matching to be sure it's only matching the files you want.

Comment: the 'build' directory which contains the already optimized and concatenated file cause the error.  Once I negate 'build' directory. Everything is perfect.  Thank you Mr. Young!

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung I have used the ignores and this does also work:    
        ignores: ['app/scripts/vendor/{,*/}*.js'] No need for a specific file !!! Thats at least my experience.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung I can't seem to get this to work in the last one of my all array: **'!' + FOLDERS.APP + "/process/*.js"**

Comment: Weird thing for me, I had to make sure my ignore was at the end of the array or else it didn't work...I think order matters here

Comment: @JLewkovich while order does not normally matter, the documentation here states that the `!` is a removal.  Therefore, if you remove something before it it added, when you add it - there it is.

Comment: @JLewkovich That fixed it for me. When using the `ignores` option, I did have to have it as the last option before it started working. I had specified individual files. Thanks for the comment!